# How to return "invalid" instead a sum of an array when input is a string or a float

Tags: ruby, methods, conditional-statements

I want to return an array of sums of multiples of 3 and 5 from 0 to n. And I want to return `"invalid"` when the input is a string, a float or < 0

```
def is_multiple_of_3_or_5(n)
    if n.class == Integer && n > 0
        n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 ? true : false
    else
        puts "invalid"
    end
end

def sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(n)

    if n.class == Integer
        i = 0
        array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5 = Array.new

        while i < n     
            array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5 << i if is_multiple_of_3_or_5(i) == true
            i += 1
        end

        array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5.inject(0, :+)
    end
end

sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(-1)
```

To get the sums of multiples of 3 and 5 I got this but when I try with -1 that return me `0` instead `"invalid", with`"string"` that return me an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this ! that worked !

```
def is_multiple_of_3_or_5(n)
        n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 || n == 0 ? true : false
end

def sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(n)

    puts n.class

    if n.class == Integer && n >= 0
        i = 0
        array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5 = Array.new

        while i < n
            array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5 << i if is_multiple_of_3_or_5(i) == true
            i += 1
        end

        return array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5.inject(0, :+)
    end

    if n.class != Integer || n < 0
        return "invalid"
    end
end
```

thanks for your help that was helpful !

Comment: Just FYI `n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 || n == 0 ? true : false` is the same as `n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 || n == 0` alone and `is_multiple_of_3_or_5(i) == true` is the same as `is_multiple_of_3_or_5(i)` alone.

Answer (score 1):

You havent' put any code in your `sum_of_3_and_5_multiples` method to handle what happens if `is_multiple_of_3_or_5` is invalid (or to put it another way, a string). You also don't need to `puts 'invalid'`, as this returns a value of null. Just 'invalid' will do:

```
def is_multiple_of_3_or_5(n)
  if n.class == Integer && n > 0
    n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 ? true : false
  else
    "invalid"
  end
end

def sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(n)
  if n.class == Integer
    i = 0
    array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5 = Array.new

    while i < n
      return "invalid" if is_multiple_of_3_or_5(i).is_a?(String)
      array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5 << i if is_multiple_of_3_or_5(i) == true
      i += 1
    end

    array_of_multiples_of_3_and_5.inject(0, :+)
  end
end

sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(-1)
=> "invalid"
```

Comment: I believe `? true : false` is redundant. A small thing: the OP wants to display `"invalid"` if `n` is a `Float` or a `String` (or is a negative number). What if, for example, `n` is a rational number? For example, `n = Rational(3) #=> (3/1)` and `n % 3 == 0 || n % 5 == 0 #=> true`, but that is precluded by only accepting integers.

Answer (score 1):

One could do that as follows.

```
def sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(n)
  case n
  when Float, String, -Float::INFINITY...0
    return 'invalid'
  end
  ((0..n).step(3).to_a + (0..n).step(5).to_a).uniq
end
```

```
sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(11.5)
  #=> "invalid" 
sum_of_3_and_5_multiples("11")
  #=> "invalid" 
sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(-340)
  #=> "invalid" 
sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(15)
  #=> [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 5, 10] 
sum_of_3_and_5_multiples(87)
  #=> [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45,
  #    48, 51, 54, 57, 60, 63, 66, 69, 72, 75, 78, 81, 84, 87,
  #    5, 10, 20, 25, 35, 40, 50, 55, 65, 70, 80, 85]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative verbose option, using a monkey patch to String class and a custom Class, stealing from Cary's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59876202/5239030) but with a three dot [`Range`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Range.html) for excluding the extreme value.

---

**Patching the `String`** class for using methods like this [Numeric#integer?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Numeric.html#method-i-integer-3F) and [Numeric#positive?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Numeric.html#method-i-positive-3F). I'd suggest to use [Kernel#raise](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) in case of error.

```
module MyStringPatch
  def integer?
    false
  end
  def positive?
    false
  end
end

String.include MyStringPatch
```

---

**Writing the custom class**

```
class MyNumber
  def initialize(n)
    raise 'Invalid' unless n.integer? && n.positive?
    @n = n
  end
  def sum_of_3_and_5_multiples
    (((0...@n).step(3).to_a + (0...@n).step(5).to_a).uniq).sum
  end
end
```

---

**Finally using it**

```
n = 32
my_number = MyNumber.new(n)
p my_number.sum_of_3_and_5_multiples
#=> 225
```

Or `...in initialize': Invalid (RuntimeError)` in case of `n = "32"` or `n = -32` or `n = 32.0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:
return "invalid" unless n.is_a? Integer || n.positive?

Taking a look at: https://rubystyle.guide/ may help

Comment: Requiring an object to not be a float or a string is not the same as requiring it to be an integer. Rational numbers, for example, presumably should not be rejected. Also, you would incorrectly return `"invalid"` if `n` were zero.